# Can we deploy custom apps that is apps made Visual Studio on sharepoint 2013 team site?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-addin, apps-development

If so then how can we deploy it. Because in my case it is hampering the UI of the team site. It is a simple hello world app. How can we add an app for team site I have created an app catalog site for team site and loaded my custom app. It is throwing some error, "Sorry, apps are turned off. If you know who runs the server, tell them to enable apps".

Comment: Did you configure Apps in your environment? Can you add Apps from the online store to your environment? Also check this out: https://mysharepointsolution.wordpress.com/2015/01/06/publish-app-to-non-developer-site-collection/ are you facing the same issue?

Comment: Yes I can't add apps from the online store of my environment and it is showing the same error. How do I add apps then on team site or how do I configure the environment?

Comment: The app related services such as "Access Database Service 2010 " & "Access Services" & "App Management Service" are already activated.

Answer (score 0):

Seems you did not configure Apps to work in your environment, it's not enough to have the App management service up and running, if you cannot add Apps from the online store, that means you did not configure Apps. You need to configure the subscription settings service application, and do some work with your DNS and in central administration. Refer to the following articles to be able to do so:

http://sharepointchick.com/archive/2012/07/29/setting-up-your-app-domain-for-sharepoint-2013.aspx   (Follow option B, it will work 100% for you).

http://blogs.technet.com/b/anneste/archive/2014/10/31/configure-an-environment-for-apps-for-sharepoint-sharepoint-2013.aspx